# Vapor web socket retaining connection to database

Tags: swift, postgresql, heroku, vapor

I am creating a web socket in my vapor code and saving data that is sent to that socket into a PostgreSQL database. The database and code is all hosted on heroku. Heroku only allows for 20 connections to the database. Creating a web socket using vapor requires a closure and that closure is retaining a connection to my heroku database even once the socket is closed. I don't know why. Here is my code.

```
func setupRoutes() throws {
    socket("log") { req, ws in
        background {
            while ws.state == .open {
                try? ws.ping()
                self.console.wait(seconds: 10) // every 10 seconds
            }
        }

        ws.onText = { ws, text in
            //print ("log is \(text)")
            let logMessage = try JSON(bytes: text.utf8.array)
            guard let instanceId = logMessage!["serverPlatformId"]?.string else {try ws.send("no platform sent"); return}
            guard let date = logMessage!["date"]?.double else {print ("no date sent"); try ws.send("no date sent");return}
            guard let percent = logMessage!["percent"]?.double else {print ("no percent sent"); try ws.send("no percent sent");return}


            let incoming = LogAnalytics(instanceId: instanceId, date: date, percent: percent)
            try incoming.save()
        }

        ws.onClose = { ws, _, _, _ in
            print ("log sokcet closeing")
            try ws.send("log socket closed")
        }
    }
}
```

I need to somehow close the connection to the database or release the connection when the socket is closed. I keep reaching my limit on the number of connections to the database and as a result I have to remove all connections and allow the server to reconnect. How do I release the connections to the database as the socket closes or even manually within the code?

Here is now the `LogAnalytics` class is setup.

```
final class LogAnalytics:Model, Preparation, RowRepresentable, JSONRepresentable, NodeRepresentable {

        var instanceId:String
        var date:Double
        var percent:Double

        var id: Node?

        let storage = Storage()

        init(row: Row) throws {
            id = try row.get("id")
            instanceId = try row.get("instanceId")
            percent = try row.get("percent")
            date = try row.get("date")
        }

        func makeRow() throws -> Row {
            var row = Row()
            try row.set("id", id)
            try row.set("instanceId", instanceId)
            try row.set("percent", percent)
            try row.set("date", date)
            return row
        }

        static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.create(self, closure: { (log) in
                log.id()
                log.string("instanceId")
                log.double("date")
                log.double("percent")
            })
        }

        static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.delete(self)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a late reply, I have been doing the same thing like you: we want to build a chat app using vapor's websockets(Latest Vapor 3.2.0). However the system cannot serve more users when database connections are used up. The solution is try to manually manage pooled database connections instead of using the default connection provided by `req` object. Here is what we do in the end(I made changes to your code as an example):

```
    ws.onText = { ws, text in
        //print ("log is \(text)")
        let logMessage = try JSON(bytes: text.utf8.array)
        guard let instanceId = logMessage!["serverPlatformId"]?.string else {try ws.send("no platform sent"); return}
        guard let date = logMessage!["date"]?.double else {print ("no date sent"); try ws.send("no date sent");return}
        guard let percent = logMessage!["percent"]?.double else {print ("no percent sent"); try ws.send("no percent sent");return}
        app.requestPooledConnection(to: .mysql).flatMap { connection -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in
                    defer{try? app.releasePooledConnection(connection, to: .mysql)}
                    let incoming = LogAnalytics(instanceId: instanceId, date: date, percent: percent)
                    try incoming.save(on: connection)

        }
    }
```